# XML display parent object in ODOO 14

Tags: xml, object, parent, odoo-14

I have created a new many2many(x_recruiters) field to hr.recruitment.stage via user interface, and I am trying to access it in the tree view of the applicant, like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<tree string="Applicants" multi_edit="1" sample="1">
  <field name="stage_id.x_recruiters"/>
</tree>
```

But it showing an error

```
Error while validating view: Field "stage_id.x_recruiters" does not exist in model "hr.applicant"
```

Can you please guide me to achieve this in the tree view, it will be very helpful for me. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find in the documentation of the `List` view that the field name is `the name of the field to display in the current model`.

The `satge_id` field is of type `Many2one` related to `hr.recruitment.stage` so you can add a related field to `x_recruiters` in `hr.applicant` then add it to the list view.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, can you please let me know ...how to write a related field to x_recruiters in hr.applicant via a user interface on developer mode activated. As I'm new to ODOO its little difficult to find the way. Thanks in advancee.

Comment: Go to ``Technical/Database Structure/Models``, click ``Edit`` then add a new item in the `field` list, set  the field name and label, and make sure to use the same type, in the `Advanced Properties` group, in the `Related Field` field specify your relation: `satge_id.x_recruiters`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will try this and let you know

Comment: Field Name :  x_recruiters
Field Label : Recruiters
Field Type : many2many
Related Model: hr.recruitment.stage
Related Field: satge_id.x_recruiters

I'm getting a validation error

Related field 'stage_id.x_recruiters' does not have comodel 'hr.recruitment.stage'

Can you please check whether my entries are correct or not

Comment: Do not provide the ``Related Model``, It should be filled when you click on the ``Save`` button. I created a similar related field with no issues.

Comment: I did as you told, the new field added but while saving the model it shows the error 

Unknown field name 'satge_id' in related field 'satge_id.x_recruiters'

Comment: It is `stage_id`, not `satge_id`.

Comment: Yes, I corrected the spelling, can you please let me know, what will be the related model and Related field...

Comment: You have to provide the field name, label, field type (`many2many`) and set the related field to `stage_id.x_recruiters` then uncheck the `Stored` property and finally save.

Comment: Thanks kenly...saved without any issues...but in a tree view, it shows only the number of records(i.e 3 records), I'm trying like this <field name="x_rec" />, how can I display the names that I selected from m2m field?

Comment: Thank you so much kenly... I achieved by <field name="x_rec" widget="many2many_tags" />, now its working as i expected..thanks for your support and valuable time..